# attr_accessors are only attribute changed trigger callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(The specific version of rails I am running is 2.3.8 but would appreciate an answer that works regardless of ruby/rails versions)

At one point, I was using an attr_accessor in one of my models to control state.
The model also had a status attribute and a function triggered by the before_update callback.

It would have looked something like this

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :bar
  before_update :revise_status


  def revise_status
    if status == "start_state"
      if bar
        self.status = "end_state"
      end
    elsif status == "end_state"
      #this was the end_state and was not supposed to be left
    end
  end

end
```

As you can see, I was using the attr_accessor as a signal that a transition should be made from one status to another.  In this way, I had effectively made a simple state machine.
I saw no reason to save a transition once it had been made, hence the attr_accessor.

This worked fairly well, except that when no attributes were changed, aside from the attr_accessor, my function did not get called.

Is there a way to make an attr_accessor behave as if it was dirty when it is something other than nil?

Comment: PS there are a number of security issues in rails 2.3.8 - at least consider updating to the latest 2.3.x version

Comment: How are you updating the record?  Can you include the code in your question please.

Comment: @FrederickCheung the application I help to develop/maintain is only used internally... and we are actually getting ready to upgrade our application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rails dirty mechanism allows you to tell it something will change, for example you could change the bar writer to do

```
def bar= value
  status_will_change!
  @value = value
end
```

which tells rail that the status column needs to be saved (it doesn't matter whether the status column has actually changed yet (or indeed will ever changed). It just ensures that rails thinks it is necessary to save that column from the record.

Comment: could I do that but use "status_will_change! unless value == nil" in order to ensure I don't make needless calls to the database when bar isn't set?